# .annotate() is not plotting all labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I've created a dataframe with stock information. When I go to create a scatter plot and annotate labels, not all of the labels are included. I'm only getting 3 labels out of 50 or so points. I can't figure out why it's not plotting all labels.

My Table:

```
        Dividend  ExpenseRatio  Net_Assets  PriceEarnings  PriceSales
Ticker
FHLC      0.0128          0.08       6.056          22.95        1.78
ONEQ      0.0083          0.21       6.284          20.24        2.26
FTEC      0.0143          0.08       3.909          20.83        2.73
FDIS      0.0144          0.08       2.227          20.17        1.36
FENY      0.0262          0.08       4.386          25.97        1.34
```

My plotting code:

```
for ticker,row in df.iterrows():    
    plt.scatter(row['PriceSales'], row['PriceEarnings'], c = np.random.rand(3,1), s = 300)


for i, txt in enumerate(ticker):
    plt.annotate(df.index[i-1], (df.PriceSales[i-1], df.PriceEarnings[i-1]))

plt.xlabel('PriceSales')
plt.ylabel('PriceEarnings')  
plt.show()
```

My graph image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ticker here is going to have the value of the ticker of the last row; e.g., "FENY". When you call enumerate(ticker), it will generate an item for each char, so it sounds like your last ticker has 3 entries.

I think you can annotate points in the same loop as the scatter plot:

```
for ticker,row in df.iterrows():    
    plt.scatter(row['PriceSales'], row['PriceEarnings'], c = np.random.rand(3,1), s = 300)
    plt.annotate(ticker, (row['PriceSales'], row['PriceEarnings']))
```

Comment: Including it in the loop worker. Can't believe I didn't think of that, but thanks for the solution!